# Adding jQuery files to ionic 2

Tags: ionic2

I am wondering if there is a way to include jQuery plugin.. for example: http://tutorialzine.com/2014/08/cool-share-jquery-plugin/
or this: http://tutorialzine.com/2013/10/buttons-built-in-progress-meters/

I am not sure of how to include these plugins... I can download them and have the script file and css file..but how to use them in my project ?

How to know that these plugins are Node-compatible modules ? 
also, if I cannot install them using npm , whats the correct way to include them in node_modules ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, install the package

```
 npm install jquery --save
```

Install (typings and) the typings file

```
 npm install -g typings
 typings install dt~jquery --global --save
```

and finally, import the jQuery to your ts file

```
import * as $ from 'jquery'
```

Comment: But after doing this @yuvii_10, I get `Runtime Error
jQuery is not defined`